# socket.io cannot find module socket.io-parser

Tags: node.js, npm, socket.io, node-modules

I've been working on a React App with a few others and it has been working great up until we added a .gitignore file and merged branches of the project which may have had different node packages installed. Anyway I'm trying to get all of the correct node packages install so I can get the app up and running again but I can't figure this one out.

When I run npm install in the working directory I get this error message.

`node_modules/@types/socket.io/index.d.ts:20:68 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'socket.io-parser' or its corresponding type declarations.`

I have uninstalled and reinstalled socket.io and socket.io-parser with npm commands and that doesn't seem to help. What's worse is that I can look through my node packages and see that socket.io parser is clearly installed and is sitting there right next to socket.io yet socket.io doesn't seem to recognize it. In fact, I went back to previous versions of the app, and copied and pasted the package.json files and node_modules to the new version manually but npm install still gives me that error. in the socket.io/index.js files I see the following line has the error shown at the bottom: where 'socket.io-parser' is underlined in the line shown at the bottom below and the error message says: "Cannot find module 'socket.io-parser' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)"

`20 import { Encoder as ParserEncoder, Decoder as ParserDecoder } from 'socket.io-parser';`